# Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: angular, typescript, download

I want to download file.docx form ws. I used in postman `send and download` and my file.docx arrived ok.

For this, I tried this code.

```
 public download(id: string): Observable<Sale[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    headers.append('id', id);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.download), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        console.log(res)    //Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(sale => {
            return new Sale(sale);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

Ts code:

```
  download(id: string) {
    this.ss.download(id).subscribe(
      saledownload => {
        console.log(saledownload)
        this.saledownload = saledownload;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You are requesting a datastream, but you cast it as a JSON object. (`let res = response.json();`)

Comment: how to write this please?

Comment: use only `let res = response;` (or remove that unnecessary line completely and use your `response` object itself)

Comment: When I change it, The StatusDescription dosen't exist in Response